# Could I select super class when creating a new class in IntelliJ IDEA 2016 like in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

As you guys know, when we create a new class in Eclipse, we can choose super class what we should extend at the same time like followed sreenshot:

In **Eclipse**:

[image: eclipse]

However, I can't do that in **IntelliJ IDEA**:

[image: IntelliJ]

Is there any menu or wizard to do this?
By the way, I'm using **Eclipse MARS** and **IntelliJ IDEA 2016**

Comment: @Makoto's answer is spot on. As a general rule, IDEA avoids wizards. Instead, it uses a "program from intentions" philosophy. This means you do things _from_ existing code (even potentially invalid code such as when you enter the name of a yet to be created method and then use intentions to create it). So in this case, our intent is to create a subclass. You start with the existing code, i.e. the superclass (or interface) and say "I want to create a subclass from you". After using IDEA for a while, you get use to this philosophy and find it to be easier in the long run. Happy coding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The feature you want is called **Create subclass**.

Use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> (or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on PC) on the class name, and you will have the opportunity to create a subclass of your currently selected class.

[image]

You may also choose to invoke this through the "Find All Actions" dialog, which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on PC and is likely similar on Mac.

Comment: What if I have a lot of classes and it's a bit of a hassle to find the code manually?

Comment: Press and release `Shift` twice to bring [Search everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html) window, then type your class name and when it's found, select it and then press `Enter` to go to class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Still I haven't found any way to select a super class while creating a sub-class in IntelliJ IDEA. But I found that option in Android Studio which looks similar to the way it is done in Eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using alt + enter --> the latest version of intelliJ has an option of "implement abstract class"

[image]